# Hyperledger ./startFabric.sh Cannot create container for service peer0.org1.example.com

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I am new to HyperLedger Fabric.
I follow the step in the following link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html to setup the development environment. When I reach step 4, using `./startFabric.sh`, it

> Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
>
> Running 'startFabric.sh'
>
> FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
>     FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
>
> Removing network composer_default
>   Creating network "composer_default" with the default driver
>   Creating orderer.example.com ... done
>   Creating ca.org1.example.com ...
>   Creating couchdb             ... done
>   Creating ca.org1.example.com    ... done
>
> ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer0.org1.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\var\\run:/host/var/run/"\nis not a valid Windows path'
>
> ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer0.org1.example.com: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\var\\run:/host/var/run/"\nis not a valid Windows path'
>   Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Docker is running, using Windows 10 Pro.
I tried many suggestions but it does not apply to my case.
Hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I couldn't find the origin of the problem but this command helped me fix it:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

Comment: Remember when giving an answer to also give a explanation on why this would fix the problem in question.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue running Docker 18.06.1-ce under Win10. I worked around this by setting the system environment variable COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS to 1 and restarting the bash terminal
Source: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1829#issuecomment-376328022 seems to be a bug in the current stable version (18 at the time of writing)

You can also revert to the previous stable version 17.x as suggested by the comment, although I havent tried that

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I solved this problem by hitting this following command on the Windows PowerShell.

```
$Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```